# Parent width not fitting to child width css

Tags: css

I am trying to make a parent div fit it's width to an image displayed. I am having a lot of trouble in doing so, it seems to auto adjust to very large.

Image: http://puu.sh/1vsqA

content is the body part

image is the white box the image is contained in

image img is the actual image inside the box itself.

CSS:

```
html, body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

body
{
    background-image: url('./page_bg.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    font-family:"lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}

#navlinks
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}

#links
{
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin: auto;
}

#links li
{
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

#content
{
    display: block;
    padding: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
}

#image
{
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
border-color: #CCC #AAA #AAA #CCC;
padding: 3px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background: #fff;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
max-width: 1107px;
}

#image img
{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try setting `#image` to `display: inline-block`. I could be wrong but I 'think' that's what you're looking for.

Here is a link example: http://jsfiddle.net/RBWYL/

Comment: That worked as well, but it seems to ignore the margin-left, and margin-right css.

Comment: I noticed that you were wanting it centered from another comment and was working on this http://jsfiddle.net/RBWYL/2/show/ I think this should work down to IE 8. check the source here http://jsfiddle.net/RBWYL/2/ and let me know if this will work for ya

Comment: I get what you're trying to do. Is there another way? and this is what happens: http://puu.sh/1vszn

Comment: It's hard to say not seeing all of your markup unfortunately. Would it be possible for you to update the jsfiddle I have in place that more closely mimics what your HTML looks like?

Comment: Yeah you can see it. HTML: http://pastebin.com/fzVk3FVq . Current CSS: http://pastebin.com/de90hYJq

Comment: If you set `#content` to `display:table` and `width:100%` that should get you centered up horizontally. Are you wanting it centered vertically as well? Here is an example loosely based off your markup http://jsfiddle.net/RBWYL/3/

Comment: Wow man, thanks! It works perfect. This was a hassle for me, so thanks for helping. :)

Comment: no problem at all man. and if you're wanting vertical alignment. here is a WIP of it... http://jsfiddle.net/RBWYL/4/show/ good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Please try to `float:left` your parent div

Comment: Hey, that worked! Now I just have to center that div somehow. IE: http://puu.sh/1vsbW